# Speed up build EAR file and skip building WAR files which don't have changes

Tags: maven, jboss, pom.xml, war, ear

I have a parent pom where I have defined profile and modules. And I have a service-all service and a pom file which inherits the parent and defines all the web modules (services) used.

This is how my parent pom looks like

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<profile>
    <id>parent-all</id>
    <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <modules>
        <module>service-all</module>
        <module>customer-service</module>
    </modules>
</profile>
```

my service-all service pom which inherits parent looks like this

```
<artifactId>service-all</artifactId>
 <packaging>ear</packaging>

 <parent>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>

<plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <version>6</version>
     <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
     <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
     <applicationName>service-all</applicationName>
     <modules>

      <webModule>
       <groupId>com.example</groupId>
       <artifactId>customer-service</artifactId>
       <bundleFileName>customer-service.war</bundleFileName>
      </webModule>
     </modules>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
</plugin>
```

So when I say

> mvn clean install
>
> mvn install

It takes over 10 mins to build the every service war file and finally build a ear out of those war files. I have close to 30 services and even a logging change takes 10 mins to test. I use JBoss Server to deploy the ear file.

Is there any way I can build only specific war files for service which has changed ? if this is possible I can bring down the time to 5 mins, because building the ear file itself takes 5 mins. Any inputs here will really help, Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something like `mvn package -pl service-all`?

Comment: Yeah I have gone through the build life cycle , the above command will only package the services. It won't look for changes , right?

My requirement is if I change a line of code in one of the 30 services, only that service should be rebuilt and package as ear file for the rest of the 29 services, including this new service which was just changed.

Comment: Have a look at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Incremental+Builds.

Comment: Thanks @JamesR.Perkins this helped me upto a certain point.